# Searching a Docker Image for a particular file

Tags: image, docker, tar

Total newb to Docker. My question is, is there a way of searching a Docker image to see if there are any Jar files present.

If I understand correctly Docker images are built in layers and each layer does not necessarily belong to that image alone. My initial approach was to "save image > image.tar" to bring all the layers together and then recursively try and search the resulting tar for the pattern "*.jar". With a standard tar if, for example, I "less filename.tar" I can see right into all of the sub-directories of the tar. This does not seem to be the case with an image which has been tarballed.

Is there a way of doing this or am I misunderstanding fundamentally how an image is built and what happens to it when it is tarballed?

Edit: I actually want to do this specifically to the image rather than launching a docker container of the image and then searching that. Is this even possible?

Edit: OK I'll try and make this clearer. I have tried to take this approach:

1) Create a tarball from a docker image: docker save image > image.jar
2) Then I've tried to search the tar for jar files with this simple script:

```
#Will list and extract all jars from a tar file
arc=$1.tar; file='*.jar'; 

tar tvf $arc | grep -E "$file" && tar xvf $arc "$file"
```

3) This will work for a standard tarball but not for a docker tarball

Again I am totally new to docker and I just want to know if there is another way of doing this.

Comment: what is the base image being used?

Comment: Any image really. Atm I am using the base java:latest to test it on as this definitely has jars in it. I can find them with no issue when i launch a container instance but have hit brick walls when trying to find them in the image alone.

Comment: What you tried and the error that your get? Please add these details by editing the question.

Answer (score 11):

Do the following

1. Run the image as `docker run -it yourimage /bin/bash`
2. Now you are in interactive mode.
3. Then use `find / -name *.jar` (if find command not available install it)

Comment: Thank you but I realise I omitted something from my OP. This is basically launching a container instance of the image? I am trying to find jars in the image without launching an instance of the image. I will edit my OP.

Comment: this is not what the question asks - besides some images don't carry the find cmd or even a shell

Answer (score 1):

The docker client has an "export" option. From a shell that has the environment configured to use the docker client run

```
docker export <your image> | tar tf - | grep etc/issue
```

which yields the following:

```
etc/issue
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Again though I do have to have a container running for this to work, yes? So far it yields the most usable results for me though.

Comment: The container doesn't have to be running, just the docker registry that's hosting the image for your container.

Comment: partially answers the question. it works on running containers, not images