# Can't seem to get circleci yml file to work for node.js project?

Tags: node.js, yaml, circleci

Apologies i'm new to writing the yml files and i've got the below config.yml:

```
version: 2.1
executors:
  my-custom-executor:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/base:stable
        auth:
          # ensure you have first added these secrets
          # visit app.circleci.com/settings/project/github/BetaONEIO/eli5_finance/environment-variables
          username: $DOCKER_HUB_USER
          password: $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
jobs:
  eli5:

    executor: my-custom-executor
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: |
          node index.js

workflows:
  my-custom-workflow:
    jobs:
      - eli5
```

However, it doesn't seem to be able to run the index.js file and I get the below error:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
node index.js

/bin/bash: node: command not found

Exited with code exit status 127
CircleCI received exit code 127
```

I'm unsure why it can't find the command? I have a package.json file so does it not build from that?

Thanks,

Comment: _"I'm unsure why it can't find the command? I have a package.json file so does it not build from that?"_ No, the reason why the `node` command  can not be found is because it is not within the [`PATH`](https://linuxhint.com/path_in_bash/). You can obtain more information by echoing it (`echo "$PATH"`) and you can verify the command exists prior use and if, display its absolute path with `command -v "${NODE_COMMAND_NAME:-node}"`. Before Circleci can execute the steps of the `eli5` job, it needs to have that command, as its second step `run` directive is making use of that `node` named command.

Comment: Please add the absolute path of the `node` command within the `eli5` job execution environment to your question by [edit]ing it. Also the contents of `$PATH` as the answer to your question depends on it.

Comment: Hi @hakre I ran echo like you said and got: 

#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
echo "$PATH" node index.js
/home/circleci/bin:/home/circleci/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin node index.js
CircleCI received exit code 0

Comment: I'm a bit confused what I do from here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know the absolute path of the `node` command for your executor or is that perhaps already "confusing"?

Comment: does the image `cimg/base:stable` has an executable file called `node` in its file-system? - https://stackoverflow.com/q/41038933/367456